# acessing music files from the iPod application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there any way to access music files that are in your music library? I was thinking of developing an application that would upload the music in the library to a server. any help would appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access music files present in your music library by using [Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html).